# Group column of arrays by week

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with two columns: `date` and `titles`. The values in `date` are of datetime type and there is a row for every individual day in a time frame of several months. The values in `titles` are each like `['Harry Potter', 'Lord of the Rings', 'Toy Story', ...]`, etc.

I want to group this data by week.

I have tried

```
df_weekly = df.groupby([df.index, pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-MON')]).agg({
    'headlines': lambda x: x
})
```

This doesn't work properly; I still have the same number of rows, just that the dates in the date column have been changed to the last day in the week that the original day fell in.

How can I get it to look like

```
date              titles
--------------------------------
2020-01-27        ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3', ...] # concatenated arr from all title arrs in that week
2020-02-03        ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3', ...]
...
```

I think a challenge is also trying to treat the arrays in the `title` column as arrays. I have tried to plug in `literal_eval` from `from ast import literal_eval`, but am not sure how to achieve what I need to do.

Comment: Normall df.index is unique for each row.  Why are you grouping on df.index?

Comment: Lack of something to group on. Can do 'date' as well, but the same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `resample` method

(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
titles = ['HP', 'TS', 'LOR']
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=14, freq='D')
series = pd.Series([titles] * 14, index=index)
```

So the data looks like

```
2020-01-01    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-02    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-03    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-04    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-05    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-06    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-07    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-08    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-09    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-10    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-11    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-12    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-13    [HP, TS, LOR]
2020-01-14    [HP, TS, LOR]
```

Now you can use `resample` to groupby a time period, here a week. Sum will concatenate your lists together.

```
series.resample('7D').sum()
```

Output

```
2020-01-01    [HP, TS, LOR, HP, TS, LOR, HP, TS, LOR, HP, TS...
2020-01-08    [HP, TS, LOR, HP, TS, LOR, HP, TS, LOR, HP, TS...
```

If you want unique values, convert the list to a set

```
series.resample('7D').sum().apply(lambda x: set(x))
```

Comment: This kind of works, except that the movie titles are not the same for every row... This creates duplicates.